# How to multiply two cells ignoring text?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, text

I have two cells, containing "*number* *text*", how do I extract numbers from them to multiply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PRODUCT(--REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2,"\d+")))
```

Assuming  A1 and A2 has the digits text combination.